# $\rm kph/MeV$ for Light yield?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, dimensional-analysis, units, particle-detectors

I was reading an article on Scintillation and I came across a peculiar unit $\rm kph/MeV$ for Light yield. It stated for Organic Scintillators, it has a Lower light yield (1-10 kph/MeV). Here do kph mean kilometers per hour or am I missing something? I am technically used to Photons per MeV for Scintillation Yield.

Answer (score 2):

As nobody else seems to have a better idea, I'll convert my comment into an answer.

Without seeing the "article on Scintillation" I can't really say what the writer was talking about, but one possibility is that they meant "thousands (k) of photons (ph) per MeV".

Comment: https://www.crystals.saint-gobain.com/products/crystal-scintillation-materials uses both (ph/MeV) and (photons/MeV) in the descriptions, so this seems very likely.